# Apple Match-O linker error: "_Main", Referance from;

Tags: iphone

Newbie Here

I was cleaning up some of my code by deleting and moving around excess code that I had been playing around with, and then I got the above error and I have no clue what went wronge or how to fix it. I was not trying to do anything really special with my app, just a few buttons, a Table View, navigation controller, and an MFMailComposeViewController.

P.S. Thanks for the help. Any leads, tips, tricks, cheats, and just plain advise is welcome.

Comment: You you paste the complete error message? Is there some file that is not part of your build target? Right click *"Groups & Files"* header and check *"Target Membership"*, make sure all source files are checked.

Comment: here is the what is it says{"_main", referenced from: Start in crt1.3.1.o Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6 Collect2: id returned 1 exit status} It also says the same thing again but with armv7 instead of armv6. Also I am using X-code 4 and I do not know where to find "Groups & Files"

Answer (score 8):

Search your project and verify that you have a global function satisfying this method signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Xcode template project will add this method in a file named `main.m`usually under the *Other Sources* group.

If the function exist, also make sure that the file is included in the targets list of *Compile Sources*.

Comment: You are awesome!!! I would have never been able to figure that out on my own.  I can't believe I deleted that file... wow. It runs beautifully now!!! Thank you. :-)